# Why does a slice in Go stack get garbage collected?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

1. I write a function to copy `string` to `[]byte`：

```golang
func unsafeStringToBytes(xxxxxs string) []byte {
    p := &xxxxxs
    sh := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(p))
    sliceHeader := &reflect.SliceHeader{
        Data: sh.Data,
        Len:  sh.Len,
        Cap:  sh.Len,
    }

    runtime.GC()
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Nanosecond)

    b := *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(sliceHeader))
    return b
}
```

2. Then, I write a test:

```golang
package gc

import (
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "runtime"
    "testing"
    "time"
    "unsafe"
)

func TestWriteLog(t *testing.T) {
    f1, err := os.Create("./log")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f1.Close()

    for i := 0; i <= 1000000; i++ {
        _, err := f1.WriteString("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB\n")
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}

func heapHeapHeap() {
    var a *[]byte
    for {
        tmp := make([]byte, 100000000, 100000000)
        a = &tmp
        _ = a
    }
}

func TestStringToBytes(t *testing.T) {
    go heapHeapHeap()

    f1, err := os.Open("./log")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f1.Close()

    reader := bufio.NewReader(f1)
    count := 1
    var firstChar byte

    for {
        s, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if len(s) == 0 {
            continue
        }
        firstChar = s[0]

        // HERE BE DRAGONS
        bytes2 := unsafeStringToBytes(s)

        _, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')

        if len(bytes2) > 0 && firstChar != bytes2[0] {
            t.Fatalf("win! after %d iterations\n", count)
            os.Exit(0)
        }

        count++
        //t.Log(count)
    }
}

func unsafeStringToBytes(xxxxxs string) []byte {
    p := &xxxxxs
    sh := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(p))
    sliceHeader := &reflect.SliceHeader{
        Data: sh.Data,
        Len:  sh.Len,
        Cap:  sh.Len,
    }

    runtime.GC()
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Nanosecond)

    b := *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(sliceHeader))
    //runtime.KeepAlive(xxxxxs)
    return b
}
```

At first, run the `TestWriteLog` to generate `log` file. Then we run the `TestStringToBytes`:

```bash
$ go test -gcflags='-m' -v -run TestStringToBytes                                                                                                                                                               1 ↵
# go_test/gc [go_test/gc.test]
./string2bytes_test.go:15:22: inlining call to os.Create
./string2bytes_test.go:29:6: can inline heapHeapHeap
./string2bytes_test.go:41:20: inlining call to os.Open
./string2bytes_test.go:47:27: inlining call to bufio.NewReader
./string2bytes_test.go:47:27: inlining call to bufio.NewReaderSize
./string2bytes_test.go:47:27: inlining call to bufio.(*Reader).reset
./string2bytes_test.go:14:19: leaking param: t
./string2bytes_test.go:17:12: ... argument does not escape
./string2bytes_test.go:24:11: ... argument does not escape
./string2bytes_test.go:32:3: moved to heap: tmp
./string2bytes_test.go:32:14: make([]byte, 100000000, 100000000) escapes to heap
./string2bytes_test.go:73:26: xxxxxs does not escape
./string2bytes_test.go:76:17: &reflect.SliceHeader{...} does not escape
./string2bytes_test.go:38:24: leaking param: t
./string2bytes_test.go:43:12: ... argument does not escape
./string2bytes_test.go:47:27: new(bufio.Reader) does not escape
./string2bytes_test.go:47:27: make([]byte, bufio.size) escapes to heap
./string2bytes_test.go:64:12: ... argument does not escape
./string2bytes_test.go:64:13: count escapes to heap
./string2bytes_test.go:90:24: leaking param: s
# go_test/gc.test
/var/folders/6w/7dl1f7mx2pv1_v48_mg37br80000gn/T/go-build1924552004/b001/_testmain.go:39:6: can inline init.0
/var/folders/6w/7dl1f7mx2pv1_v48_mg37br80000gn/T/go-build1924552004/b001/_testmain.go:47:24: inlining call to testing.MainStart
/var/folders/6w/7dl1f7mx2pv1_v48_mg37br80000gn/T/go-build1924552004/b001/_testmain.go:47:42: testdeps.TestDeps{} escapes to heap
/var/folders/6w/7dl1f7mx2pv1_v48_mg37br80000gn/T/go-build1924552004/b001/_testmain.go:47:24: &testing.M{...} escapes to heap
=== RUN   TestStringToBytes
    string2bytes_test.go:64: win! after 164307 iterations
--- FAIL: TestStringToBytes (57.46s)
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    go_test/gc  57.938s
```

As the results shows, it fails.

3. I analyze the reason why the test fails, is the `xxxxxs` has been GC, becase when I put the `runtime.KeepAlive(xxxxxs)` in the function, the failure has never recurred.

```golang
func unsafeStringToBytes(xxxxxs string) []byte {
    p := &xxxxxs
    sh := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(p))
    sliceHeader := &reflect.SliceHeader{
        Data: sh.Data,
        Len:  sh.Len,
        Cap:  sh.Len,
    }

    runtime.GC()
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Nanosecond)

    b := *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(sliceHeader))
    runtime.KeepAlive(xxxxxs)
    return b
}
```

4. BUT!!! I have a big question is that:

```
./string2bytes_test.go:73:26: xxxxxs does not escape
```

The `xxxxxs` does not escape, it is located in the go stack, How can it be GC!

Who can tell me why? Is the solution "`xxxxxs` be GC" wrong? Or any other reason?

Comment: "The xxxxxs does not escape, it is located in the go stack, How can it be GC!" ?? If the stack shrinks it's GCed automatically. "On stack" (for whatever reason) doesn't mean its memory won't be freed. It you have a pointer variable on stack the GC has to free what the variable points too. I have to admit I have no idea what your underlying problem is. You seem to want to play unsafe (for unknown reasons) and managed to shoot your foot. That's what unsafe is good for. I especially do not understand what unsafe slice to byte conversions has to do with -gcflags='-m' and escape analyse in general.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the survival mechanism of stack objects in Go, we may refer https://docs.google.com/document/d/1un-Jn47yByHL7I0aVIP_uVCMxjdM5mpelJhiKlIqxkE/edit also can see: https://go.dev/src/runtime/mgcstack.go
In function unsafeStringToBytes, the xxxxxs will not survive until the b has build, so it can be GC.

Answer (score 7):

Your code violates the [unsafe.Pointer rules](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Pointer). In particular, rule 6 specifies that you should not declare or allocate variables of `reflect.SliceHeader`.

As a consequence of this, it's possible that the GC loses track of your string when it grows/shrinks/moves the stack around.

Note that there is a simpler and safer way to do the conversion you want, in modern Go versions: `unsafe.Slice(unsafe.StringData(s), len(s))`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I know my function violates the unsafe.Pointer rules, I just want to translate the string to bytes without memory copy.  And thank you for the simpler and safer way to do what I want.  

But I do not really understand why the GC can loses track of the string when the stack grows/shrinks/moves, Is there any doc or go sdk code can verify it?  thank you again!

Comment: When the GC moves the stack around it has to adjust all pointers to variables on the stack to the new location. For that, it has to know which memory is a pointer. A `uintptr` is not a pointer. So if you convert an `unsafe.Pointer` to a `uintptr`, the GC won't adjust it. Therefore, you have to keep to very careful rules when doing that - if you do, the compiler inserts instructions to orchestrate with the GC, so it doesn't adjust a pointer in the middle of it. Your code doesn't. It stores a pointer in a `uintptr` in a way that can be interrupted by the GC moving the pointee.

Comment: I know what you say, but if the `xxxxxs` survive until the function returns, it will contain a pointer point to the memory, like below:
``` go
type stringStruct struct {
 str unsafe.Pointer
 len int
}
```
So, it is why when I put the `runtime.KeepAlive(xxxxxs)` before `return b`, it will be safe.
So, my question is: Why the `xxxxxs` can't survive until the function returns, it is a stack value, it can be survive along the function stack survive.

Comment: Oh and in terms of docs: The doc is the [unsafe.Pointer documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Pointer). There are some checks for them implemented in `go vet` and the runtime itself. But in general, there is a reason the rules exist and are what they are - the implementation is variable and is changing with ~every Go version and between implementations. It's a moving target. Stick to the documented rules or you'll end in pain. If you don't understand the rules - harsh as it sounds - don't use `unsafe`. It's finicky. Your program will be better if you don't use it.

Comment: It's not a matter of being live or not. The GC can move live memory around. The point is that you a) convert a pointer to a `uintptr` (implicitly, by putting it into an allocated `SliceHeader`) and then b) convert it back to a pointer (by converting that `SliceHeader` to a slice), with an interval in-between. In that interval, the GC can move the memory around without updating the `uintptr` you stored, or it can collect the pointee, as there is no longer a pointer to it. That's why you have to stick to the rules. To make sure there is no interval where the pointee is not pointed at.

Comment: I know, I use the `unsafe` package very very carefully on my work! I just want to know why the `xxxxxs` can not be survive until the function returns.

Comment: No offense, but empirically, you are violating the `unsafe` rules. So you are *not* using it carefully.

Comment: At the point where you inserted the `runtime.KeepAlive` call, there is no pointer alive pointing at that string data. There is a `uintptr` containing the address, but integers are not pointers. `xxxxxs` itself is not used anymore and neither is `p`, therefore there is no alive reference to that memory.

Comment: aha! NO, it is just a test when I learn about Golang and its internal mechanism, I will not use it in my work!!! Thank you for your answer, but can you explain why I put the `runtime.KeepAlive(xxxxxs)` before `return b`, It will be OK?

Comment: Because that's what's `KeepAlive` is for - it is a NOP, but to the compiler, it looks like a usage. Though, to be clear, your code is still broken even with it, the breakage is just not exposed by the current version of `gc`. Because, again, liveness is not sufficient, as the GC can move alive values around.

Comment: FTR I strongly recommend you don't use `unsafe`. It is subtle and IMO it is clear that you don't understand these subtleties around it enough to use it safely. And to be clear: *I don't use `unsafe` either*, for exactly the same reason. I don't understand the rules surrounding it well enough to be comfortable using it.

Comment: I can not agree  with you about the runtime.KeepAlive, you can test yourself.
More, I refer to: https://dev.to/jlauinger/sliceheader-literals-in-go-create-a-gc-race-and-flawed-escape-analysis-exploitation-with-unsafe-pointer-on-real-world-code-4mh7

Comment: You are making my point about not understanding the subtleties of `unsafe` for me. No, you can't "test yourself". That is just not how any of this works. Testing can only verify that a particular piece of code does something with one particular Go version. It can say absolutely nothing about what could happen if you transplant that code into a different program or compile it with a different Go version or a different Go implementation. Please, *please* introspect your overconfidence and reconsider your usage of `unsafe`. You really, genuinely don't understand it, even if that's hard to hear.

Comment: I read your blog post. It contains several inaccuracies and just plain wrong statements. In particular, your assertions about what `runtime.KeepAlive` does are wrong. Ironically, I don't think it's actually needed in that code - but more general, it's either not needed, or the code is still broken with it.

Comment: For sources, BTW: The [runtime.KeepAlive docs](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#KeepAlive): "Note: KeepAlive should only be used to prevent finalizers from running prematurely. In particular, when used with unsafe.Pointer, the rules for valid uses of unsafe.Pointer still apply."
There just is no argument that your understanding of what it does is wrong.

Comment: You keep emphasizing my violating about package `unsafe`, I can totally tell you that is a test, not production environment code. I just want to know why the `runtime.KeepAlive` avoid  the failure. I think you should not focus on the violating about package `unsafe`. Thank you!

Comment: I explained in some detail both why the code is buggy and how KeepAlive prevents that bug from being exposed. And I think you haven't read my last comment - notably, how KeepAlive *doesn't* make the code correct. It keeps a value alive, but it won't prevent it from being moved.
The reason I focus on your `unsafe` usage is that your ignorance about the rules and about what KeepAlive is and is not doing indicates that you shouldn't use it, at all. I'm not talking about the code you posted here - I'm talking about what your questions indicate about the qualification to use `unsafe`.

Comment: FWIW to repeat the explanation: 1. After you declare `sliceHeader`, there is no reference to the string data alive, 2. so the GC is allowed to collect it and 3. KeepAlive keeps a reference to the string data alive.

However 1. KeepAlive doesn't prevent the bug, as collecting is not the only thing that can invalidate a reference and 2. if the code was not buggy, KeepAlive would not be useful, but just creates memory pressure.

KeepAlive prevents the bug from being exposed, as this Go version doesn't move memory around in this case. But a different Go implementation or version might.